# How do I override onclick event for a custom html element so it only dispatches when I ask it to?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

This is an issue I am having with `oninput` and `onchange` too.

In the example below, I want to be able to have the custom element's onclick fire only when the internal button is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/xk5w95gf/

```
class TestElm extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._value = null
        this._box
        this._button
    }

    connectedCallback(){

        this._box = document.createElement("div")
        this._button = document.createElement("button")
        this._box.style.height = "200px"
        this._box.style.background = "green"
        this._button.innerHTML = "Only clicking this should trigger the outside onclick"
        this.appendChild(this._box)
        this._box.appendChild(this._button)

        this._button.onclick = () => this.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true
        }))
    }
}

customElements.define('test-elm', TestElm);
```

Right now, the onclick fires for any onclick, with clicking the button firing it twice

```
<test-elm id="myelm" onclick="console.log('clicked button')"></test-elm>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had to stop the propagation of the nested element, in the above case I just needed to add this to the `_box` element:

```
this._box.onclick = (event) => event.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: While this will work this also goes against the standard way events bubble. As long as you don't mind that, your solution should work great. But, with a Web Component, you could capture the `click` event and always allow it through and, if the click happens on the button, send an additional event to let the outside world know of that specific action.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xk5w95gf/20/

```
console.clear()

class TestElm extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._value = null
        this._box
        this._button
    }

    connectedCallback(){

        this._box = document.createElement("div")
        this._button = document.createElement("button")
        this._box.style.height = "200px"
        this._box.style.background = "green"
        this._button.innerHTML = "Only clicking this should trigger the outside onclick"
        this.appendChild(this._box)
        this._box.appendChild(this._button)


        /*
          There is no need to dispatch a `click` event on `this`
          because `this._button` is a descendant of `this`, the event bubbles up the DOM tree to `this` regardless

        this._button.onclick = () => this.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true
        }))

        */



        /*  Instead we can prevent subsequent `click` event listners from executing
            IF `this._button` IS NOT the `event.target

            Using `this.onclick = ` vs `addEventListener()` ensurs that it IS THE FIRST executing listener.

            NOTE: a simple setter like `testElmNode.onclick = newVal` will overwrite this logic.
              USE: `addEventListener()` while building your application
        `*/
        this.onclick = (event) => {
          if (event.target !== this._button) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;


            console.log('Not the button though..');
          }
        };
    }
}

customElements.define('test-elm', TestElm);
const myelm = document.getElementById("myelm")

myelm.addEventListener( 'click', () => console.log('clicked button') );
```